# How to count columns from all rows where it equals the same id?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have a table 3 table: `users`,`res_info`, `reservations`

I want to calculate the number of kilometers traveled by each driver in the trip from the highest kilometer to the lowest.

In field `total_kms`, I want to display the total kilometers per driver: for example Mohamed Mostafa Cutting distance 550 and 323 km

The following information will be displayed in the table:

```
name  ----------------   |    total kms    
mohamed mostafa          |     873
```

This my code i have tried :

```
select 
    users.name, count(res_info.res_id) as total_drives,
    (reservations.meters + reservations.meters) as   total_kms,
    reservations.meters as kms 
from 
    reservations 
    left outer join res_info 
        on (reservations.id=res_info.res_id) 
    left outer join users on (reservations.driver_id=users.id) 
where 
    reservations.zone_id = 2 
    and reservations.meters !='' 
group by 
    res_info.res_id 
order by 
    count(res_info.res_id) desc
```

[image]

Comment: need more elaboration, your code is actually SQL statement, is your question is 'how to apply it in laravel eloquent?'

Comment: `(reservations.meters + reservations.meters) as total_kms` this is just adding the field to itself, you will probably have to do this as a subquery, as its based off `per driver` and your grouping on `res_info.res_id` which who knows could have more then one driver in there before you grouped it.  So you maybe cant do it all in one query, but the schema is real vague so who knows how they are related etc..

Comment: so where('name', '=', "name")->sum('kms'); ?

Comment: for now, let's use 2 tables only for display the total kilometers per driver, without repeating the name

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please clarify: a) as @AhmedNasr noted: "your code is actually SQL statement" - which RDBMS you are using?, b) how [php] and [laravel] is related for your post?

Comment: @AhmedNasr i am using laravel 5.7, if you could do it from SQL statement  it will be better

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `reservations.meters as kms` anymore because it's breaking the grouping on the SUM. And you need to order by SUM instead of count since you want to order by most distance traveled by driver. Here is what you need :

```
select 
    users.name, count(res_info.res_id) as total_drives,
    sum(reservations.meters + reservations.meters) as total_kms
from 
    reservations 
    left outer join res_info 
        on (reservations.id=res_info.res_id) 
    left outer join users on (reservations.driver_id=users.id) 
where 
    reservations.zone_id = 2 
    and reservations.meters !='' 
group by 
    users.name 
order by 
    total_kms desc
```

Comment: I made it works normally in one of my database Album, Songs, total_songs, sum_plays. Are you sure your JOINs are correct? Can you post your table fields, the relevant ones only?